# Used WSUOffline to update windows, now when windows restarts, it tries to auto login to a temp account that isn't there.

Tags: windows, windows-update, login

How do I get this back to normal. It stops and says there's a password error, and from there I can hit "other user" and then type my name and password, but this is annoying. How do I disable the auto-login for a temp account that no longer exists (in control panel or home folder)?

I had to use WSUSOffline because NOTHING i tried (and I tried EVERYTHING) would get windows update to actually find updates, from a fresh SP1 install.

Answer (score 2):

Direct from wsusoffline help forums:

> Log in to your normal account and run .\client\cmd\CleanupRecall.cmd 
>   with admistrative rights. This should clean up the auto-logon

[Source](http://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5741)